# Declaring types in a non .ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, flowtype, google-closure-compiler

I just came across a React-native app which declares types in .js file like below:

```
this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications()
    .onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
        const notif: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
        notificationOpenedClickHandler(notif)
});
```

I have checked package.json file and there are no typescript packages. Vscode lint is underlining the `(notificationOpen: NotificationOpen)` part as red.

what is going on here?

Comment: I don't approve of the downvotes this question received. It's a perfectly reasonable thing to be confused by files containing invalid syntax for their file type.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the code is using [flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/getting-started/) for typing (used in .js files)